# Reactive Rx 2.0 EventLoopScheduler ObjectDisposedException after dispose

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm using Rx 2.0's EventLoopScheduler to queue up / serialize work. When I need to dispose the scheduler, if there is remaining work, I will receive an unhandled ObjectDisposedException. Is this the expected behavior?

contrived/sample code:

```
    EventLoopScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
    List<IDisposable> handles = new List<IDisposable>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        var handle = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
                               .ObserveOn(scheduler)
                               .Subscribe(Observer.Create<long>((x) => Thread.Sleep(1000)));

        handles.Add(handle);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    foreach (var handle in handles)
        handle.Dispose();

    scheduler.Dispose();
    Console.ReadLine();
```

stack trace:

```
   System.ObjectDisposedException
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, TimeSpan dueTime, Func`3 action)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.LocalScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, Func`3 action)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.<>c__DisplayClass50`1.<InvokeRec1>b__4e(TState state2)
   at System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver`1.Run(Object state, Action`1 recurse)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.<>c__DisplayClass50`1.<InvokeRec1>b__4d(TState state1)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.InvokeRec1[TState](IScheduler scheduler, Pair`2 pair)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`2.InvokeCore()
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`1.Invoke()
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

similar to this unanswered question: [RX2.0: ObjectDisposedException after diposing EventLoopScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109054/rx2-0-objectdisposedexception-after-diposing-eventloopscheduler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I've seen that before as well - I don't think there's a way to "flush out the event thread" per se, but you can do something like this:

```
EventLoopScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
var wrappedScheduler = scheduler.Catch<Exception>((ex) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got an exception:" + ex.ToString());
    return true;
});

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    var handle = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
                           .ObserveOn(wrappedScheduler)
                           .Subscribe(Observer.Create<long>((x) => Thread.Sleep(1000)));

    handles.Add(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not that there is work remaining (i.e. the scheduler still has things in its queue), it's that you still have Subscriptions outstanding that are trying to **add** stuff to that queue.

Dispose all of the Subscriptions and then dispose the Scheduler, and it should work correctly

Comment: I call dispose on all the handles I have before I dispose the scheduler. What more could I do?

Comment: Ah, after looking at the call stack again, it's being recursively scheduled. I would call this a bug in EventLoopScheduler though I'm not sure what you can do about it. You could certainly copy the code from https://github.com/mono/rx/blob/rx-oss-v2.1/Rx/NET/Source/System.Reactive.PlatformServices/Reactive/Concurrency/EventLoopScheduler.cs and try to hack it to do what you want

Comment: I've provided an explanation of my opinion of what's happening and the right way to go about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109054/rx2-0-objectdisposedexception-after-diposing-eventloopscheduler

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a simple way to flush the `EventLoopScheduler` queue before disposing. First, make sure that all subscriptions that are adding actions to the queue are disposed, so that nothing else can be added.

Then, simply schedule the dispose of the scheduler itself:

```
scheduler.Schedule(() =>
{
    // cleanup code: dispose of other stuff here
    scheduler.Dispose();
});
```

This last scheduled action is ensured to run after all other pending actions have run and shutsdown the thread.